# D3: when creating hierarchal structure from CSV how to add counts

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Ultimately I am wanting to use the D3 tree or cluster type functions.  I am reading in a flat CSV file and right now creating a JSON file that looks as below:

[image]

What I want to do is add a size or value attribute at each level.  So for example where Object Key is Bronze have a value 0f 27 and where Object key is CUB have a value of 1.  I tried to use the rollup but it seems that you can only use it once?

Here is the section of code that creates the object.  How is the best way to do this so I can feed it to the D3.tree or others that require that hierarchal structure?

```
// Add, remove or change the key values to change the hierarchy.
var nested_data = d3.nest()
.key(function(d)  { return d.Medal; })
.key(function(d)  { return d.NOC; })
.key(function(d)  { return d.Event; })
.key(function(d)  { return d.Athlete; })
.rollup(function(leaves) {return {"count": leaves.length}})
.entries(csv_data);


// Creat the root node for the treetop
var root = {};

// Add the data to the tree
root.key = "Data";
root.values = nested_data;
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up using underscore nest for javascript and it put the data in a format for D3